# Programmatically pass query param name to Ember's link-to component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-query-params

I'm trying to create a query param link component. The layout for my component looks something like this:

```
{{#link-to routeName (query-params filter=paramValue)}}
  {{text}}
{{/link-to}}
```

`routeName` and `paramValue` are "bound" just fine to my component class. But I'd like my component to also specify the query param name (in this case it's hardcoded as "filter". How can I bind the name of the query param to a value on my component (I want "filter" to be a variable)?

Should I just forget this method and send an action up to a route with all the properties needed to do a `transitionTo`?

Comment: From a Twitter user: "I don't think this is possible pre htmlbars, I don't think handlebars sub expressions update properly in the current impl". So not really possible yet without HTMLBars. Leaving open for the future though.